# How do I fix "copy: Bad file descriptor" in my C program

Tags: c, posix

Hello I'm working on a program that prints all the characters like a cat program by using the POSIX functions, the program has to get more than one file when it does it writes the characters of all files in the destination file.
For example;
    mycat.exe x.txt y.txt z.txt dest.txt

means write all the characters from x.txt, y.txt and z.txt in order to the file destination dest.txt that it's created after we run the program.
If any file not exits the program will not exit it prints a report that
file not exists
If any error occur, you have to exit the program.

When I compile it it compiles without any error(I'm compiling it in Windows 10), but when i try to run it it shows an error.

This is how I compile it:

```
gcc -o mycp.exe mycp.c
```

This is how i run it:

```
mycp.exe x.txt y.txt z.txt dest.txt
```

This is the error:

```
copy: Bad file descriptor
```

This is the code inside the mycp.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE     1024


void exit_sys(const char* msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void exit_fail(const char* msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void remove_dest_file(int fd, char** argv, int i)
{

    _close(fd);
    unlink(argv[i]);
}

int copy_file(int fdd, int fds)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int n;
    while ((n = read(fds, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
    {
        _write(fdd, buf, n);
    }

    if (n < 0)
    {
        return n;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fds, fdd;
    int n;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int ch;
    int flags;
    int argcm1;
    int i;


    flags = _O_WRONLY | _O_CREAT;

    if (argc < 2)
        exit_fail("usage:mycp.exe file1.exe file2.exe file3.exe ... filen filedest.exe");

    argcm1 = argc - 1;

    if (!access(argv[argcm1], F_OK)) {
        printf("The file %s exists. Do you want to overwrite?[y]\n", argv[argcm1]);
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
            flags |= _O_TRUNC;
        else
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }


    if ((fdd = _open(argv[argcm1], flags, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE)) < 0)
    {
        exit_sys("open for destination");
    }



    for (i = 0; i < argcm1; ++i)
    {
        if (fds = _open(argv[i], _O_RDONLY) < 0)
        {
            remove_dest_file(fdd, argv, argcm1);
            exit_sys("open");
        }
        if (copy_file(fds, fdd) < 0)
        {
            remove_dest_file(fdd, argv, argcm1);
            exit_sys("copy");
        }
        _close(fds);

    }
    printf("Succes");
    _close(fdd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have `for (i = 0; i < argcm1; ++i)`. You know that `argv[0]` is the executable name, not "x.txt"?

Comment: The arguments for `int copy_file(int fdd, int fds)` are that way round but you are calling it with them the other way round: `copy_file(fds, fdd)`. Voting to close as "typo".

Comment: Thank you very much that did solve the problem, now I feel embarrassed for not noticing that silly mistake :D.